# fetch current location while opening the app

Tags: ios, google-maps, core-location, google-maps-sdk-ios, currentlocation

Hi in my Application I have to show the route map form my current location to destination location. For that I'm using the `google map` URL to show the route map everything works fine. But the problem is when install the app first time its getting cash and its not fetching the current location.

When  i minimize the Application its showing the alert message like.

```
"appname" would like to use Your current Location
```

After clicking the ok its i have close the application and open it again now its showing the route map.

My code.

```
-(void)currentlocation{
     locationManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc]init];

     locationManager.delegate = self;


     locationManager.distanceFilter = kCLDistanceFilterNone;


     locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest;


     [locationManager startUpdatingLocation];


     [self->locationManager startUpdatingLocation];


      CLLocation *location = [locationManager location];


      CLLocationCoordinate2D coordinate = [location coordinate];

      mapView = [[[MapView alloc] initWithFrame:
            CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height)] autorelease];

    [self.view addSubview:mapView];

   Place* home = [[[Place alloc] init] autorelease];
    home.name = @"Home";
    home.description = @"Sweet home";
    home.latitude = 13.0051850;
    home.longitude = 77.62698590;

       Place* office = [[[Place alloc] init] autorelease];
    office.name = @"Office";
    office.description = @"Bad office";
    office.latitude = coordinate.latitude;
    office.longitude = coordinate.longitude;

        [mapView showRouteFrom:home to:office];

    }
```

I have used the above code i want like when user open the application it has to show the alert and once the user click the OK it has the show the route map please tell me how to achieve i have been stuck here for long time please help me out.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

try this pa..

```
- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateToLocation:(CLLocation *)newLocation fromLocation:(CLLocation *)oldLocation
{
    NSLog(@"didUpdateToLocation: %@", newLocation);
    CLLocation *currentLocation = newLocation;

    if (currentLocation != nil) {

        Place* home = [[[Place alloc] init] autorelease];
        home.name = @"Home";
        home.description = @"Sweet home";
        home.latitude = 13.0051850;
        home.longitude = 77.62698590;

        Place* office = [[[Place alloc] init] autorelease];
        office.name = @"Office";
        office.description = @"Bad office";
        office.latitude = currentLocation.coordinate.latitude;
        office.longitude = currentLocation.coordinate.longitude;
        [mapView showRouteFrom:home to:office];


    }
    // Stop Location Manager
    [locationManager stopUpdatingLocation];
}
```